# jquery toggle function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a form which is toggle (hide and show) with the help of button, but it is not working. Can anyone please review my code and tell why my script is not working. my code is below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add_facility").click(function () {
            $("#facility-form").toggle('slow');
        });
    });
```

```css
 .facility-form {
        background-color: #e3edfa;
        padding: 4px;
        cursor: initial;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <button class="btn" id="add_facility">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    Add Facilities
</button>
<div class="facility-form">
    <form id="facility-form1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">Internet
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">Bar
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">Free Wifi
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">Spa
                    </label>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please take care to format your question properly. This was almost unreadable

Comment: *not working* how exactly?

Comment: Can you turn on console in inspect element tool and provide the error shown there ?

Comment: Typo, voting to close: You're selecting by `id`, but your form has a *class*, not an `id`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: change $("#facility-form").toggle('slow'); to $("#facility-form1").toggle('slow'); your form id is facility-form1 but mistakenly you have used facility-form in toggle function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're selecting by `id`, but your form has a `class`, not an `id`; see `***`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_facility").click(function() {
    $(".facility-form").toggle('slow');   // ***
  });
});
```

```css
.facility-form {
  background-color: #e3edfa;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: initial;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="add_facility">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Facilities
</button>
<div class="facility-form">
  <form id="facility-form1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Internet
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Wifi
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Bar
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Free Wifi
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Spa
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Parking
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Indoor Pool
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Family Rooms
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Smoking Rooms
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the class selector not an ID selector

Change this line from,

```
    $("#facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

To

```
    $(".facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

**Here is an working Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/pz6h4g7q/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

this is mistake

```
$("#facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

change to

```
$(".facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

Comment: Why? You should explain your answer

Comment: Man just made a mistake, he knows exactly about the selectors in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$("#facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

to

```
$(".facility-form").toggle('slow');
```

facility-form is a class, not an ID.